# Deploying ASP.NET CORE Web application

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, .net-core, web-deployment

I am making a web application and am following tutorials on getting started with **ASP.NET Core** programming.

So far I have created a local SQL Server database with Entity Framework and all is fine. I want to ask about deployment.

I wish to deploy the website to a hosting server and was wondering whether the application will deploy together with the database or how to make a database work with the application on the web.

I would appreciate precise explanations and/or articles because I am confused and some articles claim that the SQL Server will need some installations and configurations.

What database type is best for .NET Core Web Apps which makes it easy for deployment? How do I make or deploy a Database to work with my web application?

I will appreciate a precise answer.

Comment: Depends on your needs. MSSQL is the default, but proprietar and expensive. I prefer open source software (.NET core itself is OS, too!) and so I'm using MySQL together with EntityFramework and the [Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql) package. I'm using this for years on .NET Core 1 and 2.1, works well.

Comment: Generally, you need a database instance of MySQL, MSSQL or whatevery is used. This could be an existing one, or a new instance. For example deloyed on Docker.

Comment: @Lion: I really appreciate your response. I am familiar with MySQL. Cost was one factor I was not motivated to use MSSQL. Your first response gave me a wider view and options. I will go with OS. This is helpful. I appreciate.

Comment: I'm glad to hear! I have posted my comments as an answer with some additional information in those direction, so you could mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your needs. MSSQL is the default in EF Core, but proprietar and expensive. I prefer open source software (.NET core itself is OS, too!) and so I'm using MySQL together with EntityFramework and the [Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql) driver package. My MySQL knowledge is also larger by experience from other projects in the past before .NET Core (e.g. PHP). I have used this for years on .NET 1 as well as the current 2.1 LTS and it worked well.

There is no *best database* at all because there are good database for each workload. For example, when having unstructured data, a NoSQL database could do the job propably better than any RDBMS.

I'd choose the database by

1. Type of data
2. Existing experience and time/wish to try something new (in corelation with #1 - I would not use e.g. CouchDB just to try out CouchDB, even this doesn't make any sense for the project)
3. Open source vs closed source with benefits and drawbags (when relevant, e.g. if you want to choose between MySQL and MSSQL)

### Application hosting

Generally, you need a database instance of MySQL, MSSQL or whatevery DBMS you choose. This could be an existing one, or a new instance. For example deloyed on Docker, or a VM. Maybe also hosted database instances in the cloud, if this is suiteable in terms of data protection. This mainly depends to your current situation. In a company you may not be able to choose each database. As a private person or freelancher, you may have more freedom.

You should think about the architecture of your entire software stack. There would be at least an ASP.NET Core appserver and database server. Maybe also some reverse proxy server, depending to your needes.

A few question which you could answer for yourself to get an idea of the hosting:

- What is the hosting platform? Do I use e.g. VMs or (Docker) container?
- Linux or Windows and why?
- Who is responsible for administration? Myself? The admin department? Or do I need some kind of managed hosting?
- How is the software deployed?
- What about different stages (e.g. test environment)?
- ...

Comment: This information is very helpful. Especially the questions that help get an idea about hosting. I really appreciate your precise response and this gave me a good overview. I appreciate.